# Resetting default behavior on form inputs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following code:

```
div.accountPage
  div.acct-form.login
    div.acct-header Log-in
    form.loginForm.login
      input(id="username", type="text", name="User", placeholder="Username", value="")
      input(id="password", type="password", name="Password", placeholder="Password", value="")
      input(id="submit", type="submit", value="Sign In")
```

During testing, I entered some username and password and hit signin. After that the textboxes contain my username and password. I dont know which property to use to reset it

How can I reset the text to go to the default behavior which is to show the placeholders?

Comment: I can. But I dont know what to code with jQuery.

Comment: Could it be related to cookies and history. I tried removing cookies however it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery:

**JQuery**

```
$(".loginForm").submit(function () {
 $(".username").val("");
 $(".password").val("");
 return false;
});
```

of course you should also add link to jquery liblary, you can download it from:

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

In your issue maybe better is set value of inputs as empty with reload page? To this you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".username").val("");
 $(".password").val("");
});
```

Comment: have you add jQuery to your project?

Comment: I did. I use jQuery other places as well. Doing an alert as well to make sure in submit function. Having said that your fiddle works even without jQuery. I removed the jQuery code and it works. I am not sure what I did that made the textboxes remember the very first input I gave. I dont have a reproducible case on jFiddle. But on my site (locally), I see the issue

Comment: Works for me now. I needed to add the above code at window load time as well

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change the value back to an empty string.

```
value=""
```